# Error - "Your Account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate" - Enterprise App

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, archive

A month or two ago, I successfully created an archive of an Enterprise app which I distributed as an ipa, which was used for internal testing. Later I changed the app name/team to upload it to the app store.

Now, I've made another change which I'd like to redistribute as an ipa for testing. However, when I try to validate the archive, it's showing me the dreaded "Your Account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate" error.

Everything seems to be ok when I check the certificate and the provisioning profile. For example, in the Enterprise account, there are two production certificates with the same name, MyCompany. One has an expiration date of 5/22/2016, which matches my provisioning profile and the certificate in my keychain, where it has the secret key showing.

The distribution provisioning profile is called  "MyCompanyMobile". It's for the App Id of   "0X000000X0.com.mycompany.*", where the wildcard app id corresponds to the app I'm working on, except for the alpha-numeric prefix. The certificate associated with it is the one I described above (i.e., the one with the expiration date of 5/22/2016).

This afternoon, I regenerated the provisioning profile, so it now has an expiration date of 5/9/2016, and downloaded it and dragged it into Xcode, where it can be seen in the account details.

The certificate definitely exists locally. I can see it in KeyChain access, where there is a certificate which says  "iPhone Distribution: MyCompany" with the same user ID - "0X000000X0" as shown on the distribution provisioning profile described above.

If I click on “preferences”, then “account”, then click on the enterprise account, there are several provisioning profiles, including the one I regenerated, “MyCompanyMobile”, with the new expiration date of 5/9/2106.

I've renamed the app from the app store name back to the Enterprise app name - com.mycompany.myapp. I also changed team back to the team associated with the Enterprise account.

I have no idea why I'm again getting the "Your Account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate" message.

I know I can revoke the certificate and go through the whole process, but I didn't have to last time.  Does anyone has any idea what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the problem, but I did manage to get the app distributed via Hockey Rink, based on this post:

http://johannesluderschmidt.de/provision-ios-ipa-app-for-in-house-enterprise-distribution/2993/

As per the post, I did this:

"Click on the project name under ‘Project’ in the center area. Click ‘Build Settings’ on the top. In ‘Code Signing’ select your distribution certificate in all fields"

and this:

"Back to the targets in the center area. Click on the project name under ‘Targets’. Click ‘Build Settings’ on the top. Choose the distribution certificate in Debug, Any iOS SDK, Release and Any iOS SDK. Under provisioning, choose the provisioning file that you have created."

After recreating the archive, it *still* didn't pass the validation test and came up with the same "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate".  But, it does create an ipa file when you export it, and I knew from past experience that the ipa probably wasn't installing due to a code-signing issue (by looking at the device log). So, knowing that the correct distribution certificate and provisioning profile had been specified, I gave it another go and uploaded the ipa to Hockey Rink, and this time it installed.

This is a fragile, complex and error-prone process. If anyone has ideas on how I can keep this from being an excruciating and time-consuming exercise each and every time I do it, I'd love to hear your ideas.